# Setting the source file character encoding for Mono's xbuild

Tags: character-encoding, mono, xbuild

I'm generating C# source code which is being built by both VS2010 and Mono's xbuild (2.10.2.0). This generally works very well, I've only had a single compatibility issue so far, and in that case I was using a 'feature' that is clearly specified as undefined behaviour (so mea culpa).

Now I'm running into an issue where I have special characters in a string literal in the C# source code. I'm generating the source files in UTF-8, the character I'm testing with is a [German sharp s: 0xC39F](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/df/index.htm). This is written to a file in latin1 by the code, where it ends up as `0xDF` when the executable is built with VS (that's the one I want) and as `0xC33F` when built with xbuild.

It does not seem to matter whether I run the executable with the .NET or with the Mono CLR, as far as I can see.

My current suspicion is that xbuild is not reading the source code as UTF-8, so the compiled code already has the wrong character in the string literal. Is there a way to explicitly tell it to? I couldn't find anything on `xbuild /?` and the [xbuild documentation](http://www.mono-project.com/Microsoft.Build) isn't particularly comprehensive. If I just missed the right page where this is documented, just a link is sufficient, of course.

All experiments have been performed on Win7 x64.

EDIT 1: To clarify, I've used a hex editor to confirm that the character in the source code file is really `0xC39F`, the character written when compiled with VS2010 is `0xDF` and the character written when compiled with xbuild is `0xC33F`.

Comment: `-codepage:utf8` sounds promising on `mcs` ([man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man1/mcs.1.html)) but I haven't yet figured out how to pass this to xbuild.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to modify the .csproj file(s) and add a <CodePage> element to the <PropertyGroup> section.

You should be able to use Visual Studio or MonoDevelop to do this for you, as well.

In MonoDevelop, if you right-click on a project and select the "Options" menu item, you can then go to the Build/General section and there will be a "Compiler Code Page" field which you can use to select "UTF-8".

FWIW, this is what MD outputs when I select UTF-8:

<CodePage>65001</CodePage>

So you can just copy/paste that into the <PropertyGroup>

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that tomorrow, but sounds good. This shouldn't affect the behaviour of VS, right? Will it preserve that setting or do I have to do it each time I edit the projects with VS?

Comment: That seems to work perfectly, thanks! xbuild on Windows now seems to read the source code as UTF-8 (xbuild on Linux always did, as I later found out) and even opening the project in VS, changing some other property and saving it again preserves the `<CodePage>` entry.

Comment: I think that is not the ideal solution. I crossed that problem just now. Adding the `CodePage` property fixes the issue for the given msbuild file, but if your project includes *targets* files from nuget references, this won't work. I think modifying these files is not appropriate. Any better idea?